# my camera app preview loves landscape

Tags: android

I am in the process of using a simple camera preview as a background for one of my activities. My problem is that the camera preview is always landscape. I have the following and nothing seems to work.

**Manifest file**

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

**Actitity_menu layout file**

```
<LinearLayout
...
    <SurfaceView
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

**Menu Activity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
    surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.camerapreview);
    surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
                           int height) {
    if(previewing){
        camera.stopPreview();
        previewing = false;
    }

    if (camera != null){
        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            camera.startPreview();
            previewing = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    camera = Camera.open();
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    camera.stopPreview();
    camera.release();
    camera = null;
    previewing = false;
}
```

Comment: Try this :         mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
inside CameraPreview class.

Comment: @DAVIDBALAS1 hi, thanks for the assistance. I have included extra code above where would I include it now.

Comment: Have you tried setting screenOrientation to portrait in that SurfaceView? Seems obvious to me for the preview to be in landscape since, well, you're setting it to landscape...

Comment: lol wow... I am not sure where to bury my head... late night and long hours...changed it though and still does not work

Comment: @ DAVIDBALAS1 it worked thanks I included it in the surfaceChanged method on top of setPreviewDisplay.. add it below for some rep points